# Android Glide data binding - wait for URL

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm trying to use Glide to load an image onto a fragment. I'm calling a service that returns the URL of the image using Retrofit and coroutines.  So my fragment has something like:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceBundle: Bundle?) : View? {
   val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(...)
   viewModel.retrieveImageUrl()
   view.imageUrl.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      imageUrl = it
   })
   binding.imageUrl = imageUrl
   return binding.root
}
```

And my binding adapter has

```
@BindingAdapter("imageResource")
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, url: String?) {
   if(!url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
      Glide.with(view).load(url).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).skipMemoryCache(true).into(view)
   }
}
```

Layout (shortened for brevity)

```
<layout>

   <data>
      <variable
         name="imageUrl"
         type="String" />
   </data>

   <ImageView
      app:imageResource="@{imageUrl}" />

</layout>
```

Everything runs properly, but the bindings execute before the imageUrl is set so the image never loads. Is there an easy way around this?  Or do I have to make the call to retrieve the URL synchronous?

Comment: Can you add your data binded layout?

Comment: I added a shortened version of it.

Answer (score 0):

use `ObservableField<String>(`) data binding property to reflect the change later.

or use `MutableLiveData<String>()`

for example.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceBundle: Bundle?) : View? {
   val imageUrl= ObservableField<String>()
   val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(...)
   viewModel.retrieveImageUrl()
   view.imageUrl.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      imageUrl.set(it)
   })
   binding.imageUrl = imageUrl
   return binding.root
}
```

and in layout

```
<layout>

   <data>
     <variable
        name="imageUrl"
        type="androidx.databinding.Observable" />
   </data>

   <ImageView
      app:imageResource="@{imageUrl}" />

</layout>
```

better use